# Debugging Jquery conflicts / errors

Tags: jquery

Is there an easy way to debug jquery conflicts / errors ?. I am currently using firebug but it is showing no errors at all. I am adding the jquery library and the jquery script and the scripting needed in the head but it doesn't seem to be working, I cant seem to get any to work to be honest, and no errors appear in firebug, so just wondering if there is anything better I can use to check for errors etc ?.

Comment: If firebug doesn't show errors - then likely there is no **syntactic** errors there

Comment: Maybe there are conflicts between some javascript you have and jquery.  You could try 'var $j = jQuery.noConflict();' in your javascript then use $j instead of $ to reference jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/web-developer/?src=search

It's brilliant and quick and has some nice other tools. The jquery/js/css/html errors are shown at the right of the toolbar.

Comment: If there were errors - firebug would show them. So not an answer